# What is the best practice to update the adapter when loading more items?

Tags: android, pagination, android-recyclerview

I have a fragment which displays a feed and every time the user scrolls the adapter will be updated by calling notifyDataSetChanged method on the UI thread.

Is this an efficient way to update the adapter?

here's the method for loading the data.

```
 private void Load(final int page) {
   myApollo.getApolloClient().query(GetpopularQuery.builder().page(page).build()).enqueue(new ApolloCall.Callback<GetpopularQuery.Data>() {
       @Override
       public void onResponse(@Nonnull final Response<GetpopularQuery.Data> response) {
           popular.addAll(response.data().Page().media());
           getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
           });
       }`
```

Answer (score 0):

Calling notifyDataSetChanged() on the UI thread is fine, but you should load data on a background thread. Loading data on the UI thread can cause the app to hang or crash if the data takes to long to load. Android came out with an architecture component last year called the [Paging Library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging/) to make loading data into your recyclerview easier. I would highly recommend reading over the documentation.

Answer (score -1):

I think that right now the easiest and recommended way to notify adapter about dataset changes is using `DiffUtils`. It gives you a possibility to decide which items have changed and which are new etc. You need to extend `DiffUtils.Callback` and implement few methods:

```
class DiffCallback(): DiffUtil.Callback() {
    override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItemPosition: Int, newItemPosition: Int): Boolean {

    }

    override fun getOldListSize(): Int {

    }

    override fun getNewListSize(): Int {

    }

    override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItemPosition: Int, newItemPosition: Int): Boolean {

    }

}
```

and setup DiffUtils to notify your adapter:

```
 val diffUtil = DiffUtil.calculateDiff(DiffCallback(oldElements, newElements))
 oldElements.clear()
 oldElements.addAll(newElements)
 diffUtil.dispatchUpdatesTo(this)
```